# Function called from button command differs from normal call ? (Python2 tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Here I define 2 class:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main2 = Tk()
        self.mainFrame2 = Frame(self.main2)
        self.mainFrame2.pack()
        self.x= BooleanVar()
        self.cb = Checkbutton(self.mainFrame2,text='tick', variable = self.x)
        self.button2 = Button(self.mainFrame2,text ='button', command = self.Command)

        self.cb.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
        self.main2.mainloop()
    def Command(self):
        print self.x.get()
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = Tk()
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.main)
        self.mainFrame.pack()
        self.button = Button(self.mainFrame,text ='Ok', command = lambda: self.callTwo())
        self.button.pack()
        self.main.mainloop()

    def callTwo(self):
        Two()
```

When I directly call

```
Two()
```

and tick the checkbox, and click the button, it prints 1

but if I call

```
One()
```

and click Ok, tick the checkbox, click the button, it prints 0

Why is that? I want to call One() and have it print 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two instances of `Tk` in a tkinter application. If you want to create more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`. You can only have a single instance of `Tk`, and should call `mainloop` exactly once.

Comment: Clear and very fast respond! Just what i needed! Thank you very much!